# Nodejs application session is not alive after closing putty terminal even after using nohup command in manage hosting server

Tags: node.js, express, putty, production-environment

I have an application running on a managed server. I deployed the application after many hurdles but now the problem is that the application process is killed once i close the putty terminal. 
I was suggested to use the following command to run the process in background, but this command is not doing any help?

```
nohup npm start --production &
```

I have googled and people have suggested to use screen, but i want to avoid using it because installing new packages brings new challenges to my app (i am new to `nodejs` deployment)

My Question : What is the problem in `nohup` command ?

**My nohup.out file :**

> Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not designed for a production environment, as it will leak memory, and will not scale
>   past a single process. connected as id 2515208

Answer (score 0):

OK so i used screen. It was pre installed on server , i just need to use it by calling a couple of commands. 
Its easy to use and my application is working fine till now. 
But still i want to know what nohup does ? because it was useless for me.